# How to resolve this packager error on react native Android

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, npm, react-native

Hello am new to react native on Android.Am doing example APP

referred this:

http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/getting-started-with-react-native-android-and-couchbase-lite

After npm start am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-70-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react_sample@1.0.0 start: `node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react_sample@1.0.0 start script 'node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react_sample package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs react_sample
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react_sample
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

can anyone what's the problem in `packager.sh` or it's problem on `cli.js`.I registry npm also & if i run app Build success full but not getting output what exactly in `index.android.js`.Please anyone help no proper solution i got on Android

Comment: Are there any lines above this? typically there is a package install failure above these lines that helps troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Packager can't listen on port 8081
 is this port problem? how to debug this? @BradBumbalough

Comment: Hey.. Got solution to this problem?

Comment: @jickson not yet please if you get solution reply back..and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You most likely already have the packager running somewhere else... run these commands.

`$ lsof -n -i4TCP:8081`

You should get a process Id (PID) returned. Run this next command with the returned Id.

`$ kill -9 <PID>`

Now try running `npm start` again.